# Visual Studio 2019 error regarding FontStyle and ControlText

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to compile a bit of VB.NET code in Visual Studio with the following code:

```
arrLozenges(i).BackColor = Color.Orange

arrLozenges(i).Font = New Font(arrLozenges(i).Font, FontStyle.Bold)

arrLozenges(i).Enabled = False
```

However, Visual Studio is reporting the following error on Build/Compile.

`'Bold' is not a member of 'FontStyle'`

`'ControlText' is not a member of 'SystemColors'.`

The program compiled code just fine but after one change (to the code I wrote, nothing about the Design of the Label and Text was change in designer view), VS2019 isn't allowing me to compile the program.

Comment: There are types with those names in both `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows`. Are those types possibly being interpreted as members of the latter rather than the former?

Comment: BTW, unless you specifically want to wipe out other styles, that second line should be this: `arrLozenges(i).Font = New Font(arrLozenges(i).Font, arrLozenges(i).Font.Style Or FontStyle.Bold)`.

Comment: *after one change*: what change(s)? What objects does `arrLozenges` contain? Are you using the same names of .Net assembly classes for your own objects somewhere?

Comment: @Jimi Literally changed one of the lines of code that I wrote. I ended up "fixing" it by literally undoing all the changes on my end and then redoing the same code change later. (By code change, I mean something like changing the logic of a `Using` loop.) I don't know why it worked, it later did.